# Need Syntax Highlighter With Hover Effect and No Scrollbars for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, syntax-highlighting

I can't remember where, but I've seen websites that have really slick boxes for displaying highlighted syntax code without scrollbars. What they did instead was use a hover effect on the box so that it gets wider to reveal all the code when you mouseover it.  I'm sure they were using CSS transitions.

Can anyone please tell me of a Wordpress plugin that will do this?  Or at least point me to some code that does it and I'll turn it into a WP plugin if I have to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are the person most likely to find the website that you have seen. And when you do, just view the source code. It will all be frontend code. Perhaps it's not even a CSS transition - perhaps, more likely even, - it's a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to this suggestion, I implemented it into Crayon :)

http://ak.net84.net/crayon/expanding-code-beyond-page-boundaries-in-crayon/

Comment: Its nice to see a plugin developer watching popular sites like StackOverflow for feedback on their plugins and then taking it into account when making updates.  Thanks for being one of those developers!

Comment: Aram, you are the man! I'll try this out! Such a fantastic feature! Its millions of times better than stupid scroll boxes!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [Crayon Syntax Highlighter](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/crayon-syntax-highlighter/) will work for you.  I'm not sure if it has a hover effect built in, but you could prob mod it to do so if you really wanted to.